# Canonical reference for rel="foo"

Tags: seo, rel

The answers to a lot of google-juice questions seem to involve the use of *rel=* in *a* tags (eg rel="canonical"). Is there an exhaustive list somewhere of all of the possible options for this tag and what they mean? I found [this](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_rel.asp) from W3 schools, but it doesn't have *canonical* on it and I'm wondering what else it's missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official link types as defined by the W3C specify the following for HTML 4.01:

> http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-links

In HTML 5 the W3C [appear to have handed off registration and management](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/links.html#concept-rel-extensions) of these link types to the [microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/faq) folks. See section *4.12.4.14` Other link types*:

> Extensions to the predefined set of link types may be registered in
> the [microformats wiki existing-rel-values page](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions). [MFREL]
>
> Anyone is free to edit the microformats wiki existing-rel-values page
> at any time to add a type.

There is also a `rel` registry which can be found here:

> http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-registry

If you scroll down you can see the stable, draft, provisional etc `rel` types. It's fairly comprehensive.

IANA also define a list of link relations which can be found here:

> http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xml

This links to RFC5988:

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988

Answer (score 1):

As far as SEO goes there are not a lot of values officially recognized for the `rel` attribute when used in the `<a>` tag. As far as I know they are:

- [nofollow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow)
- [Google authorship markup](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/06/authorship-markup-and-web-search.html)

There are other values you can add the `rel` attribute that do have semantic meaning but they have not been given specific meaning by the search engines. That doesn't mean that they aren't useful in some other way, however. `external` is a common value for `rel` in an `<a>` tag to indicate an external link but isn't an official `rel` value nor does it have SEO value.

FYI, you should also check out [schema.org](http://schema.org) for microformats. This is another way to add structure to your markup to help search engines recognize your data as being of a certain type and index accordingly.